# Iterate through list of linkservers while trying to execute SQL query as EXECUTE (@SQL) at [LinkServer]

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, execute

I am trying to execute the below -

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max), @LinkServer nvarchar(200), @min INT=1, @max INT

drop table if exists #clients;
create table #clients (Id int identity(1,1), ClientName varchar(200), LinkServer varchar(200));

insert into #clients (ClientName, LinkServer) values ('abc', 'LinkServer1');
insert into #clients (ClientName, LinkServer) values ('xyz', 'LinkServer2');

set @max = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM #clients)

WHILE(@min<=@max)
BEGIN
@SQL = 'select * from Table;'

SELECT @LinkServer=LinkServer FROM #clients WHERE ID=@min
EXECUTE (@SQL) AT [@LinkServer]

SET @min=@min+1
END
```

But it reads @LinkServer as a character. I want to run this query on multiple server, but unable to do so with the current syntax. I need to use EXECUTE(@SQL) AT [LinkServer] only.

Comment: `AT linked_server_name` *must* be a string and SQL Server doesn't support variable substitution. You would need to use dynamic SQL and **safely** inject the server name(s).

Comment: {SET @QUERY = 'EXECUTE ('''+replace(@SQL, '''', '''''')+''') AT ['+@LinkServer+']'
EXECUTE @QUERY}

Trying the below as well in the loop, but this doesn't seem to work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parameterize the `AT linked_server_name` like that, it has to be a literal.

You can do this more easily using a parameterized `EXEC`. Not many people know that the procedure name itself can be parameterized. So you just need to build a string `Server..sys.sp_executesql`

Note that the server name needs to be in a `sysname` or `nvarchar(128)`, and you need to quote it using `QUOTENAME`. Also, don't use `WHILE` just to avoid a cursor, it's silly and even more inefficient than a cursor.

```sql
DECLARE @proc nvarchar(1000);

DECLARE @crsr CURSOR;
SET @crsr = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT procName = QUOTENAME(LinkServer) + '..sys.sp_executesql'
    FROM #clients;

OPEN @crsr;
WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT @crsr INTO @proc;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BREAK;

    EXEC @proc N'select * from Table;'
END;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/3rgiF9S1)